# CSS - Make sibling DIVs of same height

Tags: html, css

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/ttsop213/

```
<div id="outer">
<div class="innerdivs" id="inner1">this has small text</div>
<div class="innerdivs" id="inner2">smallest text</div>
<div class="innerdivs" id="inner3">I think this should have a pretty large text</div>
<div class="innerdivs" id="inner4">How about making this the one with the largest text and find out how other sibling divs behave. I think something might just work, and something won't.. let us run it!    </div>
</div>
```

Requirement is to make all the DIVs of the same height. Please make sure that these inner DIVS should not have any scrollbars and the 3 DIVS should take the height of the largest DIV. Please make changes only in CSS.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where specifically are you getting stuck? The changes should only be in CSS, but what CSS? Paste all the relevant code in the body of your question and rely on external links only minimally.

Comment: Use `display: table-cell;` http://jsfiddle.net/ttsop213/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left` to keep them all on the same line and to fill the parent.

```
#outer {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 4px solid darkgreen;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.innerdivs {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ff3;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Display: table; for outer div which is having class "outer". Use Display: table-cell; for inner divs which is having class "innerdivs". And remove "float: left" property from "innerdivs".